# Definition of normal form in coq

Tags: normalization, coq

In the book Types and Programing Languages of B. Pierce, the author introduce a small language in order to introduce different concepts used through the book.

The language is the following:

```
t::=
    true
    false
    if t then t else t
v::=
    true
    false
```

There is three reduction rules:

```
if true then t2 else t3 \rightarrow t2

if false then t2 else t3 \rightarrow t3

t1 \rightarrow t1'
------------------
if t1 then t2 else t3 \rightarrow if t1' then t2 else t3
```

I would like to prove that every *normal form* is a value.

I use the following definition for the *normal form*:

```
Definition normal_form (t:term) :=
  ~(exists t',  step t t').
```

I'm stuck because at one point, I have something that looks like :

```
~ ~(exists t : term, ...)
```

and I don't see how I can infer

```
exists t : term, ...
```

since we are in a intuitionistic logic.

Here is the whole proof:

```
Inductive term : Set :=
| true : term
| false : term
| ifthenelse : term -> term -> term -> term.


Definition normal_form (t:term) :=
  ~(exists t',  step t t').

Inductive is_value : term -> Prop :=
| vtrue : is_value true
| vfalse : is_value false.


Lemma normal_form_implies_value : forall t, normal_form t -> is_value t.
Proof.
  intro.
  induction t.
  intros.
  apply vtrue.
  intros.
  apply vfalse.
  intros.
  unfold normal_form in H.
  destruct t1.
  unfold not in H.
  assert (exists t' : term, step(ifthenelse true t2 t3) t').
  exists t2.
  apply eiftrue.
  apply H in H0.
  contradiction.
  assert (exists t' : term, step(ifthenelse false t2 t3) t').
  exists t3.
  apply eiffalse.
  apply H in H0.
  contradiction.
  assert(~(is_value (ifthenelse t1_1 t1_2 t1_3))).
  intro.
  inversion H0.
  assert(~(normal_form(ifthenelse t1_1 t1_2 t1_3))).
  intro.
  apply IHt1 in H1.
  contradiction.
  unfold normal_form in H1.
  unfold not in H1.
```

Should I use an other definition for the normal form? Is it possible to finish the proof without any classical axiom?

Comment: You haven't included the definition of step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_value` is decidable,

```
Lemma is_value_dec : forall t, {is_value t} + {~is_value t}.
Proof.
    induction t;
    try (left; constructor);
    destruct IHt1;
    right; intro C; inversion C.
Qed.
```

so you can prove `normal_form_implies_value` by considering those two cases (with `destruct`), like so:

```
Lemma normal_form_implies_value : forall t, normal_form t -> is_value t.
Proof.
    induction t;
    try constructor;
    intros;
    destruct (is_value_dec t1), t1;
    apply False_ind;
    apply H;
    try (eexists; constructor; fail);
    try (inversion i; fail).
    contradict n;
    apply IHt1;
    intros [tt C];
    eauto using scomp.
Qed.
```

`scomp` is a constructor for `step`, using this definition:

```
Inductive step : term -> term -> Prop :=
| strue:  forall t1 t2, step (ifthenelse true  t1 t2) t1
| sfalse: forall t1 t2, step (ifthenelse false t1 t2) t2
| scomp: forall t1 t1' t2 t3, step t1 t1' -> 
          step (ifthenelse t1 t2 t3) (ifthenelse t1' t2 t3).
```

Answer (score 2):

One interesting lemma to prove is the inversion lemma stating that if `ifthenelse b l r` is in normal form then so are `b`, `l` and `r`.

```
Lemma normal_form_ifthenelse (b l r : term) :
  normal_form (ifthenelse b l r) ->
  normal_form b /\ normal_form l /\ normal_form r.
```

Which can be proven rather easily if you are willing to use a lot of help from the automation machinery.

```
Proof.
   intros H        (* assumption "normal_form (ifthenelse b l r)" *)
 ; repeat split    (* split the big conjunction into 3 goals *)
 ; intros [t redt] (* introduce the "exists t',  step t t'" proofs
                      all the goals are now "False" *)
 ; apply H         (* because we know that "step t t'", we are going to
                      be able to prove that "step (ifthenelse ...) ..."
                      which H says is impossible *)
 ; eexists         (* we let Coq guess which term we are going to step to *)
 ; constructor     (* we pick the appropriate constructor between the structural ones *)
 ; eapply redt.    (* finally we lookup the proof we were given earlier *)
Qed.
```

If that's a bit too much automation for you, you can try to prove manually the following (simpler) lemma because it's the bit we are going to need in the final proof:

```
Lemma normal_form_ifthenelse (b l r : term) :
  normal_form (ifthenelse b l r) -> normal_form b.
```

Your lemma can then be proven rather quickly: in the two first cases of the induction, using `constructor` will pick the right `is_value` constructor.

In the last one, we are provided with an induction hypothesis `IHt1` saying that provided that `t1` is a `normal_form` then it `is_value`. We can use our intermediate lemma to prove that `normal_form t1` based on the fact that we know that `normal_form (ifthenelse t1 t2 t3)` and conclude that `is_value t1`.

But the fact that `t1` is a value contradicts the fact `normal_form (ifthenelse t1 t2 t3)`: we can indeed step to either `t2` or `t3` depending on whether `t1` is `true` or `false`. `False_ind` is a way for us to say "and now we have derived a contradiction".

```
Lemma normal_form_implies_value : forall t, normal_form t -> is_value t.
Proof.
intro t; induction t; intro ht.
  - constructor.
  - constructor.
  - destruct (normal_form_ifthenelse _ _ _ ht) as [ht1 _].
    apply False_ind, ht; destruct (IHt1 ht1); eexists; constructor.
Qed.
```